# How to set value to input type date using JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating an update page in which value for the input type date will come from the database.

I am able to get value from database and it is stored in a string but when I set this value to date field using below code

```
 <input type="date" name="rdate" value="<%=dateFromDB%>" />
```

I get this error:

```
Bad value "dateFromDB" for attribute "value"
```

`dateFromDb` is a `String` and has value `2013-04-01`.

Please help to set the value?

Comment: You can try this : <input type="date" name="rdate" value=<%=dateFromDB%> />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
<input type="date" name="rdate" value='<%=dateFromDB%>' />
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working when I run the program, but in the jsp page it is showing the same error ( I am using Netbeans). can you explain why this is?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is showing in netbeans with red line

Answer (score 0):

**You can use JSTL tag library that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.**

This sample code might help you:

```
<c:set value="10/23/2014 - 15:15:22" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject"
                                      pattern="MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm a" />
```

Please read more at  [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL6.html)  and get them [here](https://jstl.java.net/)